# partial layout did not change when change the screen orientation changed

Tags: android

I have a app stated well, but when I change the orientation some view's layout in the viewpager's fragment is still use the before orientation. like this(the tabbar is OK, but the image view and the text is not working well,I guess the fragment did not have `onLayout()` step?):

[image]
[image]

I have set the android:configChanges like this below to the corresponding activity in activity tag

```
android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize
```

I have searched a lot in google and stackoverflow, but seems there is no solution. so please suggest me a solution.

the layout file is like this(sorry for some reason, I can't paste my xml code, so I descripe it as explicit as I can):

```
activity has a viewpager, view pager has two fragments, the fragement's view has a linearlayout use gravity="center",and the linear layout has a vertical orientation with a imageView and textView.
```

Comment: Add the layout xml file, we will try to help.

Comment: @Rajasekhar sorry, I can not paste my xml code, because it is not allowed in my company.

Answer (score 0):

I could have been much easier if I see your xml. But let me give you simple solution by making `ConstraintLayout` as new parent.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    tools:context=".HomeFragment">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image_view"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:src="@android:drawable/btn_star"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/hor_guide"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        tools:ignore="ContentDescription" />

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/hor_guide"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.5" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="My Custom Title"
        android:textSize="32sp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/hor_guide" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

`ConstraintLayout` works in all scenarious. So test your orientation changes with this.
In this layout I made use of `Guideline` which is not visible to the user, but helps us constraint the other views with respect to it.